# Nuxt optimization

Tags: webpack, optimization, nuxt.js

I would like to reduce unused code im my Nuxt project. I use unused-webpack-plugin for Vue.js projects. It works gteat. I try to add it into Nuxt. But it does not work. What am I doing wrong? Maybe there is another good option, another plugin for Nuxt? Nuxt version: 1.4

*nuxt.config.js*

```
const UnusedWebpackPlugin = require('unused-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    extend(config, { isDev, isClient }) {
       if (isDev && isClient) {
         config.plugins.push(
              new UnusedWebpackPlugin(),
         )
       };
    }
}
```

Comment: `Nuxt version: 1.4`?? Sure about that one? Otherwise, this is quite a broad question, depends on what you're using in terms of packages.

Comment: Full verion: "nuxt": "^1.4.2" 
Ancient...

Comment: Yeah, bump it towards 3, to begin with. I recommend starting a brand-new app tbh.

Comment: I am not able to start a brend-new app. I have updated a project into "nuxt": "^2.16.3". But the question is still relevant.

Comment: Want more performance overall? Migrate to Nuxt3. The rest of my initial comment is still valid. There is no magic switch to x3 the speed of your app. People hire performance consultants for a reason, it's not a quick and easy thing to achieve.